# Use Siri commands for a specific app

Tags: iphone, siri, youtube

I have wondered to my self if I can search on YouTube through Siri (iPhone 6s), when I have tried the "help" with Siri it(she?) showed me how can I use it with Facebook and twitter.
My questions are this:

> 1. How can I use "help" for a specific app (like "help with YouTube ") and get all the commands I need for the specific app.
> 2. Are there any commands in the YouTube app? (like if the YouTube is closed and I want it to be open and search for a specific song)

Comment: Just might... but I asked it before the other guy